# Is the "tr1/rand" header available in Dev C++? In GCC?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

If it's possible in Dev C++ Version 4.9.9.2
Please tell me how to use it!!

If not tell me where I can download the required version of GCC/C++?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Dev C++ hasn't been updated in 7 years. You should switch ides (and compiler).

Comment: @JesseGood I thought Dev C++ work was ... restarted?

Comment: I would suggest using Codeblocks or codelite instead.

Comment: @pst: At one point yes, but AFAIK the newer version has been in beta for 4 to 5 years.

Comment: If you are uncertain if a specific header file is available or not, why not just try to include it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:I included it and got No such header file.I thought maybe I had not included those files during installation.So which C++ should I download?Version?For using the this header file.I need it for my TopCoder Marathon Matches.For testing on random inputs.

Comment: There is a recent effort going on a [Dev-C++ fork](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.de/).

Answer (score 1):

Why should an IDE have anything to do with the headers provided with the Compiler?
If you use Dev-C++ (which i don't recommend due to its age) with the latest g++/gcc (for instance from [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) you should have the header available.

Comment: I have the latest Dev C++ version and it does not have the rand header, what say?Maybe I have not chosen it while installing?Actually I remember choosing everything for installation.

Comment: You must substitute the bundled gcc version with a newer one. See link in my post to a newer one.